# How do I add Bango SDK to my android project?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am trying to incorporate Bango SDK with my project. Just wondering if anyone has done that or has an idea? 
The link is as follows:
http://bangoandroidsdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/103062

I was wondering how do I import their SDK (which consists of jarfile/bin and src) and doesn't show up everytime I try to do an import. 
Also, is there any way i can add it to my project and set some targets? Can anyone lead me through this step by step (new to android) , so I can add it and get it to work? (Also, can you please specify the relevant code changes required and where I can call the application ID)

Thanks in advance!
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the package, there `.jar`, you have to add them into `Libs` folder of your project and `import` them to your java class.

You can also import the entire project as an project in your IDE and edit you project properties to link it as a library.

Refere to the page linked :

> RELEASE NOTES
>
> The zip file includes compiled JAR file, Source code including a Test
>   App Harness, and documentation in PDF for version 1.4.2 of the Bango
>   Android Application Analytics SDK.

EDIT ANSWER QUESTION UNDER (get from PDF file linked on the page linked):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // your code
   // Check if activity is being restored from a saved instance
   if (savedInstanceState == null)
   {
       BangoAgent.onStartSession(this, ApplicationId);
// your code }
}
```

Comment: wherei n my code do i add the application id code and the relevent code in oncreate/ondestroy?

Comment: i never used this library before, but all answers are in the PDF and `Documentation` page. Please read before asking.

Comment: I saw that, but i have no clue where to add the onstartsession where I am to add the application ID in numbers

Comment: I have copy that on my first answer. In our onCreate method and change `ApplicationId` by your interger (your id). All is here.